# Link to Django Admin

Tags: python, django

Being relatively new to Django and despite studying the documentation I am somewhat stuck and would greatly appreciate any help.

I have a template for a list view that is only available for staff.

I want to be able to click on the indidvidual link in the list and be taken through to the individual item in the admin.

At the moment I have the following in the template which works fine although only as an 'experiment'

```
<a href='{% url 'admin: contacts_contact_changelist' %}' {{ contact.id }}
```

How do I go about implementing the link and is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go to a particular contact's edit page use:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:contacts_contact_change' contact.id %}">link name</a>
```

This is described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls).

Comment: Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more information, take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to SO!